# android:exported="true" not working and not letting flutter app be installed in android 12

Tags: flutter, android-12

app working properly with iphones,ipads and android 13 butnot working android 12.  im using Dio() package.

and unable the request.

manifest. file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

minSdkVersion 21 in gradle.

does anyone have this problem

---

this is my manifest file.. can you check for me. thanks..

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.boldbadge.boldbadgeadmin"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    
    <application
        android:label="boldbadgeadmin"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
         
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
                  <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
       android:value="high_importance_channel"
       android:resource="@raw/order" />

   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
       android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
       android:resource="@android:color/white" />   
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
      <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
              
    </application>
</manifest>
```